# how to make length of input box same in firefox and chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a input field in my website design. When I coded like this as shown in below

HTML:

```
 <input type="text" name="lemail" value= "" placeholder="Email" id = "lemail"/>
```

CSS:

```
  *{
     font-size:12px;
     font-family: sans-serif,helvetica,arial;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     -ms-box-sizing: border-box;

  }  

  #lemail{

      position: absolute;
      top: 40px;
      left: 20px;

      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-top: 8px;
      padding-right: 20px;
      padding-bottom: 8px;
      border: 1px solid #007599;
      border-radius: 3px;

   }
```

captured photo results:

CHROME:
[chrome output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc4b3.png)
FIREFOX:
[firefox output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btouj.png)

here the problem is input box length is different in chrome and firefox. In firefox length is a larger than in chrome.Border-box did not work.
how to make input field look same in both browser?

Comment: Set width for input.

Comment: You have to set width for your input :)

Comment: Thank you :-) I did not check that.

Answer (score 1):

define width to your box like as in below code **width:250px;**

```
#lemail{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #007599;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width:250px;
}
```